# Is there any gem to integrate paypal button api to rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, paypal, paypal-buttons

Is there any gem to integrate paypal button api to rails application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a good solution is to integrate [activemerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) .
it works great with the paypal gateway.

look at the example on github [page](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)

Answer (score 1):

The one gem you need is activemerchant. If you still need a step-by-step instruction on how to integrate it, check out: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/10/24/integrating-paypal-express-with-rails-3-1-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

activemerchant is the best way to integrate Paypal..You can refer http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics
http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant Rails casts tutorial.
 Still there are some other gems like [paypal_adaptive](http://www.webtempest.com/paypal-adaptive-with-rails-3/) i got on google..
You can try this also.
http://webtempest.com/paypal-adaptive-with-rails-3/